# Alphabetical Core Data Table

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to make a table view with a list of contacts loaded from Core Data in my app.

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController.

On starting the app, I extract contacts from the Address Book and add them to Core Data. This is so I can manage contacts independently of the Address Book. On creating a contact object I have a create method which includes the following code:

```
contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];
contact.name = name;
NSString *initial = [name substringToIndex:1];
NSString *capitalisedInitial = [initial capitalizedString];
contact.nameInitial = capitalisedInitial;
```

This saves the first letter of the contact into an attribute of the contact object.

In my table view controller code I set up the NSFetchedResultsController as follows

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contact"];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor1 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"nameInitial" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor1, descriptor2, nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.contactsDatabase.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"nameInitial" cacheName:nil];
```

My problem arises only the very first time I run the app (after deleting the app from the device). When I open the contacts page straight after opening the app, it shows a completely blank table, and it doesn't refresh at any point. If I close down the app (not delete) and restart it the table works fine.

The other strangeness, in the last line of code above, if I remove @"nameInitial" and use nil instead for sectionNameKeyPath, everything works fine with no glitch. However I really want to have these sections, as the alphabetical column for shortcuts which is added is expected by the user.

I guess it has something to do with the database not being ready or something when the table first loads, but I thought these fetched results controllers were supposed to listen for updates to the database and update accordingly when it's ready?

Any thoughts really appreciated...

EDIT:

Some further info:

On first load the numberOfSectionsInTableView delegate method returns 0. This seems to be cause of the problem. On subsequent loadings it returns the correct number. I have logged the fetched results controller and it is fetching a full set of results every time...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number of Sections = %i", [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]]);
   return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

Comment: Does your `NSFetchedResultsController` have a delegate? Have you implemented the delegate methods?

Comment: Yep. As I said it works fine the second time I open the app, just not the very first time when the database is being created...

Comment: Working fine the second time doesn't imply that the delegate methods work. In fact the symptoms you describe are pretty consistent with missing or incorrect implementations of those methods.

Comment: Sorry for delay and thanks for reply Tom. I've subclassed the Stanford CoreDataTableViewController which mostly just copies the code from NSFetchedResultsController's documentation page into a subclass of UITableViewController. This implements the delegate methods.

Comment: Added some new info there after some de-bugging...

Comment: @Alan - Implementing the delegate is one thing, actually connecting up your delegate so that it calls those methods is another. Do you actually set the delegate somewhere (either in code or in your XIB)?

Comment: Yep, I thought that might be the problem myself so I've tried setting it in a few places. I am setting it equal to self, the class that I'm subclassing is an NSFetchedControllerDelegate. Given that I've established it's calling numberOfSectionsInTableView: , that would indicate it's working okay?

Answer (score 0):

Are you [responding to changes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW28) properly? From the documentation...

> Changes are not reflected until after the controller’s managed object context has received a processPendingChanges message. Therefore, if you change the value of a managed object’s attribute so that its location in a fetched results controller’s results set would change, its index as reported by the controller would typically not change until the end of the current event cycle (when processPendingChanges is invoked).

It sounds like after your initial import your context is not processing it's changes and therefore not notifying your FRC

Comment: I've subclassed the Stanford CoreDataTableViewController which mostly just copies the code from NSFetchedResultsController's documentation page into a subclass of UITableViewController. This manages the changes. I would imagine that if the problem were with this code, there would have been more fuss about it?